# Will acetone damage/attack anti UV coating on glasses?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, materials, solvents

My glasses collect a lot of grime in hard to reach spots. I want to dunk them in acetone to loosen the grime and clean them.

Does this put me at risk of losing the anti-UV coating? Sorry I was unable to find out what the coating chemical was.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the material your glasses are made of, I would discourage cleaning glasses with acetone.

Often, glasses use no longer use glass as [lens material](https://www.thevisioncouncil.org/content/lens-materials/adults) -- polymers like polycarbonate represent an alternative, especially if a high degree of correction is intended, or simply because of weight concerns.  [Polycarbonates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate#Properties_and_processing) however withstand ketones (and acetone is an example of ketones) poorly ([listing](https://www.calpaclab.com/polycarbonate-chemical-compatibility-chart/)).  As a result, contact with this solvent may blind your glasses permanently.  Happens to safety goggles worn in the chem lab, too -- yet better the goggles, than damage to the eyes.

In addition, what is the material of the frame?  Hence, I recommend a mild detergent; and if this is not working, consult your optician -- they have an ultrasound bath.

Answer (score 0):

Different types of lens materials and coatings use different chemical compounds. ***However it is typically advised not to use solvents or anti-bacterial soap to clean your glasses, regardless of what type they are***, as it can lead to damaging of the scratch-resistant coating, UV coating, etc.

For a definite answer, you can call your optician and ask him/her about the coating used and whether or not it would be safe to use acetone to clean your glasses.

I would say your best bet would be to get an eyeglass cleaning kit made specifically for the purpose of cleaning glasses as those have been tested and proven to not be damaging to the materials used.